# Phonegap: save HTML5 page data in database

Tags: jquery, database, cordova, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

I am creating a webapp, that will be wrapped in iOS and Android using Phone gap. The HTML pages will have some data entered by user. I want to save this data in database using jQuery and without writing any code in Android and Objective C. So in future we only update jQuery code if required.

I need you people suggestion for possible approaches.

Thanks

Comment: You want to save into a server side or client-side database?

Comment: In device database only

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have multiple options. The easiest being localstorage/websql.

**Localstorage**

```js
var myData = {
   key: "value",
   otherKey: "otherValue
};

// To save
localStorage.setItem("user_data", JSON.stringify(myData));

// To retreive
var myData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_data"));
```

**WebSQL/SQLite**

WebSQL is a fully functional SQL database running in the browser (doesn't work on WP platform). An alternative is using the cordova SQLite plugin:
https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage too, but if your data is too large to hold in local storage, then you need to use sqlite plugin of phonegap to store data into sqlite database.